# How can I prevent multiple users of same system from generating same reference number

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a software (Laravel based) that tracks the movement of files. The end users would be mostly admin officers (might be more than 3 of them). When a file gets to their department, they register it with the software.
Upon registering a new file, a reference number is generated when the page loads (using the ID from the database).

Suppose admin officer A tries registering a new file (i.e loads up the page), but maybe gets distracted along the way (his reference number is already generated), and then admin officer B goes ahead and registers a new file.  When admin officer A goes ahead to submit the form, they will both have registered a file with the same reference number seeing as the reference number is generated using the date and ID of the most previous DB entry.

How can I prevent this from happening or is there a more efficient way I can go about this?

Comment: Couldn't you generate the ID in the backend after the form was submitted?

Comment: *"How can I prevent this from happening or is there a more efficient way I can go about this?"* Generate the reference ID in the database when everything is uploaded/saved/inserted, generating a reference ID on a form load is asking for race conditations to happen..

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reference number needs to be displayed in an input box for reference purposes. It may also be edited/deleted because some files already have a form of reference numbers.

Comment: *"Couldn't you generate the ID in the backend after the form was submitted?"* @Bolphgolph what happens if two forms where uploaded to the same time you still could have a race condition.. As we don't know the code which the topicstarter is using.. Generating the reference ID in the database is most likely the best bet

Comment: How about you create an "empty" db row in the database that has the auto generated id and you show that id on the form. Perhaps with a "status" of "not submitted" or something. Then, when the form gets submitted, you update the db row and update the status.

Comment: *"How about you create an "empty" db row in the database that has the auto generated id and you show that id on the form."* @MER ID in forms can be changed on the clients side..

Comment: Well then, if the client can change the id manually, there really won't be a way to ensure uniqueness. Perhaps when they go to "submit" the form, you make an ajax call to do the `INSERT` and if it fails due to duplicate key, tell the user and have them try a different id.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend generating the id from server side after the form is submitted.

Comment: agreed. don't generate the ID until the form is submitted and data committed

Comment: Is that what would you recommend or what @Bolphgolph recommended 3 minutes before you?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments! Seeing as the admin users would be logged in, A friend of mine suggested appending a unique ID of the logged in user to the generated reference number in that case it will always be different for multiple logged in users working at the same time.